# UTF8 Find Replace Tool?

Tags: xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, replace, notepad++

Forum Members,
I am coding in XML and using a validator / parser that chokes when it encounters a UTF8 related text hiding within my text.  I am using NotePad++ in ANSI mode, and when I switch it to UTF8 mode it shows me where these UTF8 errors exist. Once I manually delete the unwanted UTF8 text character my validator/parser works perfectly.

NotePad++ is not able to find and replace UTF8 characters within an XML file. My question to anyone out there. Does a NotePad++ plugin exist that will let me globally search the file for unwanted UTF8 text and replace it with NOTHING? Also, can a RegEx find and replace unwanted UTF8 text? Is there a text editor out there that is capable of hunting down unwanted UTF8 text?

In addition, can anyone out there educate me about UTF8 text and why do they prevent an XML validator from working correctly?  I spent several hours trying to figure out why my XML code was not successfully parsing and it would of been a lot easier if I would have had the ability to hunt down unwanted UTF8 characters.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use **Editplus 3**. You can try it by yourself.

At the other side, could you mind to show some text of your XML code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "utf8 text"? Is it just set of chars not from `chr(0)..chr(127)`? If so, SynWrite editor can hilite such high ascii chars, if you activate "Text russian detector" lexer (by calling lexers menu clicking statusbar lexer name).

You can adjust this RU-detectioon. In Lexer propeprties dialog you can change regex for RU chars.